# Wordpress site doesn't show menu departament right

Tags: wordpress

I am following a tutorial but there is a problem when I save the menus created for my departament. The theme that I have is electro and I created some static contents to add them to the menu. This is what I got and I don't understand why [image] Any idea what was the mistake? I added them by using backend editor and choosing elements TextBlock
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use HTML blocks. Text block won´t work.
If HTML blocks aren´t avaible, maybe "personalized code" or something like that.

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smBbZWwnW6o at 1:32:37 for him is working

Comment: Yours is not being read as html, it is showing the code instead. Old tutorial probably. Another option is to paste that code in the text block, but selecting "HTML" instead of visual.